# Scraping Investopedia using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the trade page on Investopedia using selenium.

I want to make selenium type the ticker (which is a string variable) in the symbol field on the webpage. However, it doesn't work and returns an error.

Minimal reproducible example (the email and password used are temporary)

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

def login():
    driver.get(r'https://www.investopedia.com/simulator/home.aspx')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('garewof922@sofrge.com')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('Epefx8yGqFzSZL/')
    driver.find_element_by_id('login').click()

def getTradePage():
    tradeUrl = 'https://www.investopedia.com/simulator/trade/stocks'
    driver.get(tradeUrl)
def setStock(ticker):
    driver.find_element_by_id('input-179').send_keys(ticker)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="list-item-141-0"]/div/span[2]').click()

chromeOptions = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chromeOptions)       
login()
getTradePage()
setStock('hvt')
```

Error returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/basselabdulsabour/Investopedia-Bot/shit.py", line 24, in <module>
    setStock('hvt')
  File "/home/basselabdulsabour/Investopedia-Bot/shit.py", line 18, in setStock
    driver.find_element_by_id('input-179').send_keys(ticker)
  File "/home/basselabdulsabour/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 472, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/home/basselabdulsabour/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/home/basselabdulsabour/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/basselabdulsabour/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="input-179"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55ba23ebcb33 <unknown>
#1 0x55ba239856d8 <unknown>
#2 0x55ba239bb6f1 <unknown>
#3 0x55ba239bb8b1 <unknown>
#4 0x55ba239ee574 <unknown>
#5 0x55ba239d908d <unknown>
#6 0x55ba239ec2fb <unknown>
#7 0x55ba239d8f53 <unknown>
#8 0x55ba239aea0a <unknown>
#9 0x55ba239afad5 <unknown>
#10 0x55ba23eee2fd <unknown>
#11 0x55ba23f074bb <unknown>
#12 0x55ba23ef00d5 <unknown>
#13 0x55ba23f08145 <unknown>
#14 0x55ba23ee3aaf <unknown>
#15 0x55ba23f24ba8 <unknown>
#16 0x55ba23f24d28 <unknown>
#17 0x55ba23f3f48d <unknown>
#18 0x7f2212455927 <unknown>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Email/Password combo is no more valid :/

Comment: this page doesn't have id `input-179` but `input-192` - but they may send HTML with different values.

Answer (score 0):

This server generates new `IDs` everytime when I refresh page so it doesn't have `input-179`.

You have to use other values to recognize element.

For this field you could use:

```
placeholder="Look up Symbol/Company Name"
```

The same problem have next line which try to select option from list.   It also has new `ID` but you can use

```
role="option"
```

It makes other problem - this element (and inner elements) are not `clickable` (probably because there is no `<a>` or `<button>` or `<input>`) and it may need to use `JavaScript` to click it.

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', elemenent)
```

---

```
def setStock(ticker):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Look up Symbol/Company Name"]').send_keys(ticker)

    #driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@role="option"]').click()

    option = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@role="option"]')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', option)
```

---

Full working code (tested on `Chrome` and Firefox`):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
#from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names`

def login():
    driver.get(r'https://www.investopedia.com/simulator/home.aspx')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username').send_keys('garewof922@sofrge.com')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys('Epefx8yGqFzSZL/')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login').click()

def get_trade_page():
    url = 'https://www.investopedia.com/simulator/trade/stocks'
    driver.get(url)

def set_stock(ticker):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Look up Symbol/Company Name"]').send_keys(ticker)
    
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@role="option"]').click()
    
    option = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@role="option"]')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', option)

# --- main ---

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

login()
get_trade_page()
set_stock('hvt')

#driver.close()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! I have another question if you don't mind: why do we have to use time.sleep() when logging in? It doesn't work otherwise. I think username and password fields appear at the same time. What's wrong?

Comment: I saw `sleep` in your code and I keep it - but sometimes pages may run code which checks if email is correctly constructed. I think on this page once I had problem because it clicked `login` before text was in password field so I added `sleep` after password. It runs some JavaScript code to put text and sometimes it may need small delay - all depends on page.